# ScrollView is not smooth when loading HTML content into Label CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

i am making status app where all status are being fetched from my Wordpress Website , all working fine but i found some problem when i fetch html content and showing it in cells using UILabel. when i fetch default excerpt all works fine but when i add tags like

etc in excerpt then scrollview is not smooth and it stopped sometime , although i don't get any error in Xcode.. this is the code how i convert html to text..

```
 cell.titleLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString:newsData[indexPath.row].excerpt.rendered)
```

please help.. thanks

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same issue as different questions. Stick to the discussion on your previous post.

Comment: Is `String.init(html:)` a custom method? If yes, you need to share it, we can't guess what's wrong with it. If you use `NSAttributedString` init with HTML Data, and keep only the `string` property of it, the init is slow, that's how it's done in the SDK, and since it's in main context...